# how to get vlan information through IP address

Tags: switch, router

How to get VLAN information of switch through IP address?

Comment: Please clarify the question. It has no sense as it is.

Comment: What JFL said. Also, you can't derive any VLAN information just by seeing an IP address until you actually know the network in question and know which IP addresses are used in which vlan.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific about what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

An IP address contains no information about VLANs or switches. IP is a layer-3 protocol which is carried inside layer-2 frames, such as ethernet. Layer-3 is blissfully unaware of which layer-2 protocol is encapsulating it. An ethernet frame may have VLAN information in the ethernet header (see [802.1Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1Q)).

Comment: In fact, RFC1149 describes how to send IP via carrier pigeon. It wasn't written purely as a joke; the goal was to catch any avoidable Layer 2 dependencies in the IP specs (especially since telecom carriers would have had strong incentives to sneak such dependencies in).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a Cisco switch, you can try to read the [CISCO-VTP-MIB](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/9/CISCO-VTP-MIB.html) with an SNMP tool.

For example:

```
nms-server2:/home/ccarring> snmpwalk -c public 14.32.100.10 vtpVlanState
```

More information: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/41003-catalystVLANinfo.html